# Can I change the cage on a Campagnolo Chorus derailleur?

Tags: derailleur-rear, campagnolo

I have a Campagnolo Chorus 10 speed rear derailleur that will not shift properly.  I've  aligned the frame, adjusted the high and low settings and attempted to fine-tune the shifting with the barrel adjusters but it will not shift properly.  The cage itself appears to be slightly out of alignment.  Can this be serviced, or better yet swapped out for the cage on a 10-speed Daytona derailleur( that I happen to have)?

This question is not a duplicate as the Campagnolo products are different from SRAM or Shimano and I was specifically asking about replacing parts, not how to adjust the derailleur.

Comment: If the cage is out of alignment, then it usually means that something is bent.  This could be the cage itself, the hanger arm, or in fact any other part of the derailleur. Take it to a Local Bike Shop to have a look at.  It's sometimes just a 1 minute job to straighten it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to straighten a bent derailleur hanger?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/how-to-straighten-a-bent-derailleur-hanger)

Comment: There are several answers to similar questions if you search for [derailleur hanger](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=derailleur+hanger)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play in Jockey wheels Sram X7 rear derailleur](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20878/play-in-jockey-wheels-sram-x7-rear-derailleur)

Comment: I don't think its a dup necessarily -- campy is different than sram/shimano, but I don't know enough about specific campy things that one could say that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daytona and Chorus use different cage fixings, so swapping a Daytona cage in in place of a Chorus 10s one is not possible.

Daytona used a circlip, Chorus uses a tubular bolt to secure the cage to the lower pivot assembly of the rear derailleur (RD).

Unless the RD has been crashed, or the cage has been "snagged" by the spokes of the rear wheel, it's unlikely that the cage is deformed.

More likely is that the rubber o-rings that set the amount of float on the top pivot have softened with prolonged contact with mineral oil and the RD is no longer hanging dead square - this assumes that you have done a full & correct RD set-up.

If you want to send us the RD for checking, we can do this ...

HTH

Graeme

Campagnolo main UK Service Centre

www.velotech-cycling.ltd.uk

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed response, that is exactly what I needed to know.  I am in the US so sending it for service would be cost prohibitive for me.